# Comment traduire « knowing is half the battle » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Le contexte c'est le dessin animé des années 1980 contenant des « [messages d'intérêt public](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwYPMpBdink&list=PL906596BF9876D73A) » sur la sécurité etc. destinés aux enfants, par exemple sur les dangers des rivières et lacs à moitié gelés l'hiver :

> — Hey Joey, watch this!
>  — Davey, come back the ice could
> brake!
>  — Ahah you're breaking my heart! Ahhhh help me!
>  — Hold
> it, don't go on the ice, you'll only add weight...
>  —
> Snow Job!!!
>  — Find something that'll reach...
>  — This branch
> ought to work...
>  — Remember, frozen ponds and rivers may not be
> totally frozen...
>  — We could be skating on thin ice... Now we
> know!!
>  — And **knowing is half the battle!**
>  [...]
>
> [ Snow Job - "[Be careful around frozen ponds and lakes](https://youtu.be/_Hth4GxNTXA)" - A G.I.
> Joe PSA, Hasbro. ]

*Merriam Learners* explique que [*half the battle*](http://half%20the%20battle) c'est « an important and necessary part of doing or achieving [accomplir] something ». On trouve diverses traductions :

> *It's half the battle*/la partie est presque gagnée ([*Larousse anglais-français en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/battle/564845))
>  *That’s half the battle*/c’est déjà
> bien ⧫ c’est à moitié gagné ([*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/that-s-half-the-battle))
> Être conscient du problème est la moitié du problème ?
> ([*Wordreference forums*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/knowing-is-half-the-battle.3715312/))
>  Grâce à..., la partie est déjà à
> moitié gagnée. ([*Wordreference forums*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/knowing-is-half-the-battle.3715312/))
>  Une parfaite
> connaissance du problème permet d'en résoudre une bonne part.
> ([*Wordreference forums*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/knowing-is-half-the-battle.3715312/))
>  Savoir, c'est gagner la moitié de la
> bataille. ([*Wordreference forums*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/knowing-is-half-the-battle.3715312/))
>  Problème reconnu est à
> moitié résolu. ([*Wordreference forums*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/knowing-is-half-the-battle.3715312/))
>  Le savoir est le nerf
> de la guerre. ([*Wordreference forums*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/knowing-is-half-the-battle.3715312/))

Dans un film de 2009 qui reprend les personnages, celui de Général Hawk emploie encore l'[adage](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1046173/quotes/qt1014216) et on traduit en français par « savoir, c'est vaincre ».

---

- On peut assurément remettre en question la sagesse de l'affirmation «
  [Know](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/know)ing is [half the battle](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/half%20the%20battle) » mais qu'en est-il de sa
  traduction  : quelle traduction est la plus fidèle, idiomatique et convient le mieux à l'exemple et pourquoi ?
- Pourquoi « savoir, c'est vaincre » est-il adéquat ou non ?

Answer (score 6):

Dans ce contexte, le sens exact n'est pas important. Il est plus important d'avoir une formule idiomatique, simple, qui peut servir de refrain.

Donc j'utiliserais l'expression française courante

> [Savoir, c'est prévoir.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22savoir%20c%27est%20pr%C3%A9voir%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

C'est une expression un peu vague mais qui signifie qu'une étape nécessaire pour éviter le danger est de le reconnaître, ce qui est similaire à l'expression anglaise même si c'est un peu moins fort.

Je ne sais pas quelle est l'origine de cette expression. Il y a plusieurs expressions du même genre qui jouent sur des rimes en -oir :

> [Voir c'est savoir, et savoir c'est prévoir.](https://www.proverbes-francais.fr/citations-prevoir/) (Alexandre Dumas)
> Pouvoir, c'est savoir. (origine inconnue)
> Prévoir, c'est pouvoir. (origine inconnue, probablement une adaptation d'une citation d'[Auguste Comte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_Comte) « Savoir pour prévoir, prévoir pour pouvoir »)
> [Vouloir c'est pouvoir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vouloir_c%E2%80%99est_pouvoir).

On pourrait aussi dire [« un homme averti en vaut deux »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un_homme_averti_en_vaut_deux), qui est un proverbe et a le même sens, mais je trouve que c'est un peu moins adapté à un public d'enfants.

Answer (score 2):

Une traduction intéressante en cela qu'elle est littérale peut être lue dans le dictionnaire bilingue *Harrap's*.

> **that's half the battle**  c'est bataille à moitié gagnée

Cependant, la forme traduite n'est que le noyau d'un nœud de contextes qui orbitent autour de cette idée de bataille à moitié gagnée.
Par exemple, le même dictionnaire donne pour « youth is half the battle » la variante  « *il n'y a rien de tel que d'être jeune* ». Mieux encore, pour « the first blow is half the battle » la traduction prend un tour différent dans « *le premier coup en vaut deux* ».

Le dictionnaire bilingue *Robert & Collins*, qui classe cette expression comme familière, ne fournit pas une traduction aussi typifiée ; cette traduction, « *c'est déjà pas mal* » (aussi de registre familier), n'élève pas l'idée au rang d'adage.

Selon cette philosophie de traduction et dans le contexte donné, la correspondance « *savoir c'est bataille à moitié gagnée* » est une option non négligeable, mais, à mon avis, « *un homme averti en vaut deux* » est dans ce contexte particulier de danger tout aussi valable et même plus pertinent.

Comment: Malgré le raisonnement un peu trop emberlificoté à mon goût, +1 pour « homme averti en vaut deux » qui me semble le seul équivalent (je récuse le mot de « traduction » pour ce qui est adage, proverbes, etc.) possible. Pour céder à l'air du temps bien sûr on peut proposer « personne avertie en vaut deux », dont la fréquence est en train de prendre le pas sur son équivalent « unisexe » (aisément vérifiable par un ngram).

Answer (score 1):

Je suggèrerais :

> « Être prévenu, c'est déjà beaucoup »

ou encore tout simplement :

> « Nous voilà prévenus ! »

***Concernant les autres suggestions :*** à mon sens « c'est bataille à moitié gagnée » est par trop littéral, ce n'est pas une expression courante et le lecteur va se demander de quelle bataille il s'agit (Austerlitz ? Gergovie ? Dunkerque ?!!). « Savoir, c'est prévoir » n'es pas vraiment approprié, et pas une expression courante non plus (n'en déplaise à Dumas). « un homme averti en vaut deux » est pas mal, mais certainement pas dans la bouche d'enfants qui s'expriment rarement par proverbes.

Comment: @némésie-t-île À mon sens « c'est bataille à moitié gagnée » est par trop littéral, ce n'est pas une expression courante et le lecteur va se demnder que quelle *bataille* il s'agit. « Savoir, c'est prévoir » n'es pas vraiment approprié, et pas une expression courante non plus (n'en déplaise à Dumas !). « un homme averti en vaut deux » est pas mal, mais certainement pas dans la bouche d'enfants.